# Display Failure of image in ENVI

Tags: envi

Fig.1 is the image in zoom of 15.5% ,and Fig.2 is fixed zoom in 59.0%.

Obviously,Fig.1 window fails to display.However,the image can display regularly after zooming into a certain percentage.

What is the reason for display failure of Fig.1?

[image]

```
                                        Fig.1
```

[image]

```
                                        Fig.2
```

Comment: Make sure you have enabled Pyramids in your ENVI preferences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Luke Indeed Pyramid's setting leads to problems. There are 3 items about Pyramid settings in ENVI, like picture below.
[image]